# I can't encode my input

Tags: python, byte, encode

```
if wb == 'Encode a sentence' or wb == 'encode a sentence':
    print("Please enter the Sentence...")
    str = input()
    str = str.encode('base64','strict')
    print(str)
```

It tells me that it can't be bytes, They should be string...Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Im using python 3.5.0

Comment: On a side note, it's probably best to use a different variable name instead of `str` since that is a built-in in Python and can be used for things like `str.encode('my string')`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
import base64

if wb == 'Encode a sentence' or wb == 'encode a sentence':
    print("Please enter the Sentence...")
    str = input()
    base64.b64encode(bytes(str, 'utf-8'))
    print(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
from base64 import b64encode
b64encode(wb.encode())
```

also for your if line use this

```
if wb.lower() == 'encode a sentence':
```

Comment: Thanks! a Lot my friend